# Geometric thickness of $K_{15}$.

Tags: graph-theory

Dillencourt, Eppstein and Hirschberg have written a paper titled
"Geometric Thickness of Complete Graphs" (publicly available at http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9910185v1.pdf).

Theorem 4.1 in this paper has a short (and easy to understand) proof that the geometric thickness of $K_{15}$ is 4,
except for one thing: their "case 1: 3 points on convex hull" does not cope with the possibility that there
are duplicates among the nine points they find. I am probably overlooking something obvious, but I cannot see what.

To demonstrate one specific case: why is it "obviously" impossible that a 3-layer geometric embedding
of $K_{15}$ has a layout like the figure below, where $A,B,C,X,Y$ are vertices of the $K_{15}$
and the remaining 10 vertices are in the interior of the parallellogram $PYQC$ (the edges have no meaning, apart from clarifying the location of the points)?

This layout would make both $A_1$ and $B_1$ from the proof equal to $X$,
and $A_2$ and $B_2$ equal to $Y$ which breaks down the proof.

[image: figure 1]

Comment: That paper is odd. He does not even need Theorem 4.1. Contrary to what he says the result follows from Theorem 3.1! All the values of x in the range 1,2,...,7 give the expression in the range 3.1 to 3.5. The max is greater than 3, but the geometric thickness is an integer so it must be at least 4.

Comment: @almagest: I am afraid you miscalculated. Theorem 3.1 gives a lower bound of 3 for $n\in\{10,\ldots,15\}$.

Comment: You are right. Arithmetic was never my strong point! x=3 gives (105-6-3)/(45-6-7)=3 and x=2 and x=4 are smaller. Thanks.

Comment: So in your diagram above Z would be the 11 edges: AB, BC, CA, AX, AY, XY, BX, BY, CC1, CC2 and C1C2 (because you can only count XY once). So each layer would have at most 31 edges outside Z giving a max total of 11 + 3x31 = 104. So the argument still works, just, because we need 105 edges. Is that right? In other words, the paper has an error, but not a serious one.

Comment: @almagest: Thanks, I think this nails it. I was focused too much on finding out why that configuration is impossible instead of seeing that, even if it occurs, we have enough "slack space". If you convert your comment to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have certainly identified an error in the paper.

In your diagram above the set Z would be the 11 edges: AB, BC, CA, AX, AY, XY, BX, BY, CC1, CC2 and C1C2 (because you can only count XY once). So each layer would have at most 31 edges outside Z giving a max total of 11 + 3x31 = 104, not 102 as he states in the paper.

But his argument still works (just) because we need 105 edges. So the error is not that serious.